# Asynchronously call-in to a Managed Package

Tags: integration, metadata-api, platform-event, isv, webhooks

I am working on a Managed package App that makes callouts to a well-known external REST API. Some of the Endpoints are asynchronous, meaning they just give back a Job Id. Currently, ugly [Apex is polling a second endpoint](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/370940/256) to check whether the result is ready.

The obvious improvement would be that the External Service signals Salesforce that results are ready and technical solutions for that are listed below. Each have drawbacks that make me wonder what to do:

1. **Platform Events:** It's Salesforce-specific signaling. The External Service would need to change something specifically for Salesforce-based clients. Something they don't want.
   I also fear the complexity of making that work from a Managed Package. I don't want subscribers to set up Connected Apps or other Auth artifacts.
2. **Apex REST Webhook:** A nice generic solution but the Setup in Salesforce will be cumbersome and not fully automatable with code. To make the Endpoint reachable from the outside a Domain and a Site need to be created, configured and connected to a packaged Webhook class.

How did/would you decide? Are there other options? Did I miss something?

Comment: How about exploring [apex continuations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/apex_continuations.htm)?

Comment: Apex continuations are only usable in the context of VF/LWC Controllers If I am not mistaken. If that would be the case, a simple setInterval would be worth to consider as well, but I do not think it is the case. @Robert Sösemann have you consider an autolaunched flow that pauses and resumes after specified time? As an alternative for schedulables or queueables

Comment: Very nice idea @GabrielSerranoSalas. Could you outline that a bit in an Answer?

Comment: Sure, I will ellaborate a proper question soon today

Comment: What capabilities does this external platform have? Could it, say, send an email, which you could then set up an Email Service handler? You're allowed two minutes of callout time, maybe you could call some sleep hook for like 1:50 to keep Apex alive? Can the request complete in two minutes? Could you make it synchronous anyways? A Queueable chain might be convenient as well, or maybe a Batchable class that polls until it's done?

Comment: @GabrielSerranoSalas You are right, continuations make sense in Lightning/VF context only. I should have clarified that in my response whether the use case involved Lightning components. However, I'm curious to see how you would design this with flow pause/ resume functionality as it might have its own use case based limitations.

Comment: You mentioned you don't want subscribers to set up their own Connected Apps, but would you be willing to create your own Connected App and then have subscribers run through the standard OAuth flow one time with an integration user?

You can hit Apex REST endpoints as if they were part of the standard Salesforce API from from the following relative path `/services/apexrest/NAMESPACE/CustomURL`

If your external service has the OAuth refresh token stored of the integration user it should be able to call back into that Apex REST endpoint when the job completes.

Comment: @ScottCovert you mean the ISV app provider sets up a Connected app ONE time? org Admin needs to do so or my package code needs to set it up using MDAPI... Do I package it?   I thought each Subscriber Can you elaborate on that in an answer?

Comment: @RobertSösemann Yes, you can package a Connected App, and have an OAuth flow in your external app for every subscriber.  Once the OAuth flow is complete, that can be used for that subscriber to make REST API calls from the external platform against that subscribers SF org

Comment: Connected App packaging is for 1GP I believe. There are problems trying to do this in a 2GP. Do you really have to have separate connected apps for each subscriber org? Could they not all use the same connected app? After all, it sounds like they are all connecting to the same external service. Each org would have to be connected to and refresh/access tokens obtained independently, through use of a single Connected App. We, as an ISV, do similar for a mobile app, with the Connected App existing on our PBO.

Comment: @PhilW that is a very helpful answer. Would you mind adding it as a real answer with a few details? The how to configure in PBO and how the subscribers then handle it (including references to SF docs) would be awesome. Because there is no such document from Salesforce.

Comment: If you go with an Apex REST Webhook on a public Site, note that there are several headers which are not allowed (cookie, set-cookie, set-cookie2, content-length, authorization), so you won't be able to use those, you'll have to come up with custom header names to validate the traffic. Not a problem with custom traffic, but if you're trying to support some existing notifications that only have the capability to do basic auth headers, that might be a problem.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_restrequest.htm?search_text=restrequest

Comment: Very helpful @MatthewLamb!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would engineer this to leverage a [Connected App](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.connected_app_overview.htm&type=5), using a server-to-server authentication flow. Salesforce supports [OAuth 2 JWT flow](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&type=5) for this purpose.

The Connected App should [not be packaged](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/135408/50252) (I know there's a [knowledge article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.connected_app_how_to_install.htm&type=5) mentioning packaged Connected Apps, but that is not a recommended approach in my book and [doesn't work with 2GP](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/367230/50252)), but instead created on the ISV's PBO (Partner Business Org). It can be shared by each and every customer of the ISV in the integration between the external service and their specific org - when the Connected App is first used against an org it gets set up in that org (if desired its use can then be [monitored or even restricted or banned on that org](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.connected_app_manage.htm&type=5)).

The external service simply requires access to the necessary details for the Connected App (client ID etc.) and the correct end-point on the customer org. It performs whatever authentication is required, when required, then should invoke some API on the org with the necessary authentication token and data.

If you did package a Connected App in a 1GP, each install gets a unique client ID etc. which makes wiring it up with the external service far more complex.

Comment: Yes, this is the correct approach - you definitely do not want to have one connected app per customer as this would be a logistical nightmare.

What makes this confusing is Salesforce's decision to have Connected Apps 'live' as metadata within an individual org. They should have created some separate portal like api.salesforce.com/apps similar to how other providers like Slack handle their developer apps.

There's no putting that genie back in the bottle though, so the best thing to do is make sure they're created in an org you won't lose access to, ideally your PBO as @Phil W suggested.